Rigging: Lead/Drag/MOvement bone
I am trying to rig a character. And I have an issue. I am trying to add a bone that will hang above the character and handle directional movement for it. All it would do is drag the rig, but for some reason, the bone doesn't pull the skeleton with it. How would I make it so that the hanging bone make the whole rig move.


